# Let $f(x) = [(x/2)\sin x -(1-\cos x)]$. The smallest positive integer n

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) =[(x/2) \sin x -(1-\cos x)]$. What is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)/x^n$ is nonzero?

I tried solving it. Got $n=3$. But the answer provided was 4. Any hints?

Comment: Did you try using Taylor series or any other method? Please show the approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^n}\left(\frac{x}{2}\sin x-\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cos x}\right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x^n}\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}\right)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{1}{(1+\cos x)}\right)\frac{1}{x^{n-2}}$$

Can you see why the minimal is $n=4$? Please, try find the limit using $n=3$ and check what goes wrong.